# Calling An Addition Method For An ArrayList of Class Objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I am currently working on a program where I must collect data and calculate the correct output by adding digits and modifying them according to the following number for each. The class I made for transactions is this:

```
public static class OrderTransactions {
    String no;
    String loc;
    String co;
    String val;

    public OrderTransactions(String n, String l, String c, String v) {
        no = n;
        loc = l;
        co = c;
        val = v;
    }

    public int TotalAmount(ArrayList<String> x) {
        HashMap<Character,Double> hm = new HashMap<Character,Double>();
        for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
            String[] s = x.get(i).split("(?<=\\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])");
            hm.put(s[1].charAt(0), Double.parseDouble(s[0]));
        }

        double[] nums = new double[5];
        int i = 0;
        for(Map.Entry<Character,Double> pair : hm.entrySet()) {
            switch(pair.getKey()) {
                case 'M' : 
                    nums[i] = pair.getValue() * 1000000;
                    break;
                case 'K' : 
                    nums[i] = pair.getValue() * 1000;
                    break;
                case 'H' : 
                    nums[i] = pair.getValue() * 100;
                    break;
                default : 
                    System.out.println("Info did not have correct following letter");
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println(nums[i]);
            i++;
        }

        int tot = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++)
            tot += nums[j];

        return tot;
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble with the TotalAmount method when I call it in the main like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    OrderTransactions[] obj = new OrderTransactions[5];
    String info;

    for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter input as: 'num;loc;co;val'");
        info = sc.nextLine();
        String[] parts = info.split(";");
        obj[i] = new OrderTransactions(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
    }

    ArrayList<String> costs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        costs.add(obj[i].val);
    int tot = obj.TotalAmount(costs);

    System.out.println("Total Amount: " + tot);
}
```

I'm trying to calculate the sum of all the parts "val" of the array of my created class. The problem is I cannot call it using an array of the objects on the "int tot" line. I've tried calling it for obj[i] but that doesn't give me the correct calculation. How would I go about calling the TotalAmount method from my array of class objects

For more information, I am supposed to modify numbers by the following letters, such as "234K" and "1.3M". When the code is run, input would look like "1001;Online;Target Corp;234K", "1002;Store;Advantec Corp;1.3M", and "1003;Online;Marvel Brothers;2.1M".

Comment: Unrelated: start by using *good names* consistently. I have **no** idea what your fields within OrderTransactions are supposed to mean. BEyond that it is really unclear what exactly your code is supposed to do. So please read [mcve] carefully and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Please do not** name a funtion starting by apper case like`public int TotalAmount(ArrayList<String> x)`
name it like `public int totalAmount(ArrayList<String> x)`

2) try to move this method `public int totalAmount(ArrayList<String> x)` to main class and make it static.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    OrderTransactions[] obj = new OrderTransactions[5];
    String info;

    for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter input as: 'num;loc;co;val'");
        info = sc.nextLine();
        String[] parts = info.split(";");
        obj[i] = new OrderTransactions(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
    }

    ArrayList<String> costs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        costs.add(obj[i].val);
    int tot = totalAmount(costs);

    System.out.println("Total Amount: " + tot);
}
public static int totalAmount(ArrayList<String> x) {
    HashMap<Character,Double> hm = new HashMap<Character,Double>();
    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        String[] s = x.get(i).split("(?<=\\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])");
        hm.put(s[1].charAt(0), Double.parseDouble(s[0]));
    }

    double[] nums = new double[5];
    int i = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<Character,Double> pair : hm.entrySet()) {
        switch(pair.getKey()) {
            case 'M' :
                nums[i] = pair.getValue() * 1000000;
                break;
            case 'K' :
                nums[i] = pair.getValue() * 1000;
                break;
            case 'H' :
                nums[i] = pair.getValue() * 100;
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println("Info did not have correct following letter");
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(nums[i]);
        i++;
    }

    int tot = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++)
        tot += nums[j];

    return tot;
}
public static class OrderTransactions {
    String no;
    String loc;
    String co;
    String val;

    public OrderTransactions(String n, String l, String c, String v) {
        no = n;
        loc = l;
        co = c;
        val = v;
    }


}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using these constraints and naming since it's a company practice assignment that I'm doing in my spare time. Otherwise I probably would have went about this differently.

Comment: Naming method names using an upper case letter is a very common practice. Don't know why someone would emphasize so hard on not doing it.

Comment: It's because of Java coding convention. You can check java library and the syntax of methods and classes.  http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/10/10-java-best-practices-to-name-variables-methods-classes-packages.html